# Getting all the json value inside array lop

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

```
{
   "id": 67,
   "firstName": "Chethan",
   "middleName": "B",
   "lastName": "V",
   "installerType": "Individual",
   "installerserviceModel": [
     {
       "installerServiceId": 33,
       "category": {
         "categoryId": 39,
         "categoryName": "Network",
         "categoryDesc": "Telecom",
         "categoryServicemodel": [
           {
             "serviceId": 10,
             "serviceName": "Network one",
             "serviceDesc": "Network one",
             "isActive": 0
           }
         ],
         "active": 0
       },
       "categoryServiceModel": {
         "serviceId": 10,
         "serviceName": "Network one",
         "serviceDesc": "Network one",
         "isActive": 0
       }
     },
   ]
}
```

How to get all the service Name details inside this data using angular 4.

I have a value stored in "selected Value" keyword and i need to access all service name inside this response how to achieve it using angular 4.

How to display all the service Name details using *ngFor loop in angular 4.

I have a value stored in "selected Value" keyword and i need to access all service name inside this response how to achieve it using angular 4

Comment: Could you please format your question a bit? Such as adding end-of-sentence marks (?.;!), removing duplicated sentences. Could you also clarify what is "selected Value" keyword and how it is related to the question?

Comment: selected value is a variable which is storing this data

Comment: use a data.installerserviceModel.forEach(c=>{miarray.pus(c.categoryServicemodel)})

Comment: @Eliseo what is miarray ??

Comment: an array that you define as miarray:any[]=[] over you iterate later

Comment: i am getting error as Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Did you change the 'data' in @Eliseo's example to your "selected Value" variable?

Comment: yes i changed it my selected value

Comment: `"categoryServiceModel"` will have always same under `category` and `installerserviceModel`?

Comment: yes @ShashikantDevani

Comment: Ok, than have you tried this : `this.selectedValue.installerserviceModel.map(x => x.categoryServiceModel.serviceName);`

Comment: yes i got the values thank you @ShashikantDevani

Comment: @chethu, WC, I have added it to answer, please mark it, if its help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

`this.selectedValue.installerserviceModel.map(x => x.categoryServiceModel.serviceName);`

Answer (score 1):

in component.ts

```
this.item = this.selectedValue.installerserviceModel.map(
x => x.categoryServiceModel);

console.log(this.item);
```

in component.html

```
<a *ngFor="let data of item">{{data.serviceName}}</a>
```